# How to resize Dataframe in python to include first row in Source/PDF

Tags: python, dataframe, resize

please help.

Python Dataframe reads/return data as below from pdf missing/excluding first row. This could be because of how pdf was generated at source.
[sample data image in dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCOJF.png)
Is there a way to resize or restructure to pick first row of the table too?
please help.

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd

file = "sample.pdf"
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=1, multiple_tables=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(tables[0])
df = df.reset_index()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],row[4])
```

Comment: Try `tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=1, multiple_tables=True, stream=True)`

Comment: thanks RJ however it still won't return first row.

Comment: looking forward to some more assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the output image, tabula has considered the first row of your data as header of the table. This might have happened because of no header present so Tabula has considered first row as column names.

Easiest way to stop Tabula from converting first row as column header is to use pandas_options parameter of Tabula.

Add that parameter like below:

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=1, multiple_tables=True, pandas_options={'header':None})
```

This should stop Tabula to convert first data row as your column headers.

Comment: thank you so much. that resolved my issue.